# JPA/Hibernate Save child with Composite Key that relies on Parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am looking for a way to save where the database generates the Id (`@GeneratedValue`) and that value be cascaded to a child object that is part of a Composite Key. Let's say we have the following `Parent`:

```
@Entity
@Table("PARENT")
public class Parent {

    private long id;
    private List<Child> children;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="...")
    public long getId() {
        return this.id
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="key.parent", cascade= { CascadeType.ALL })
    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }
}
```

With a Child:

```
@Entity
@Table("CHILD")
public class Child {
    private CompositeKey key;
    private String value;

    @EmbeddedId
    public CompositeKey getKey() {
        return this.key
    }

    public void setKey(CompositeKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    // .. basic mapping of value column

}
```

And Composite Key:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeKey key {
    private String type;
    private Parent parent;

    @Column(name="TYPE")
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("PARENT_ID") // FK in the Child table
    public Parent getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how this could work where the id for `Parent` can be saved and set as part of the FK in `Child` as part of the `CompositeKey`